# .net core 1.1 upgrade issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I upgrade my .net core to new version 1.1 but I got error when running my projects built in version 1.0

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Found dotnet SDK, but did not find dotnet.dll at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-003121\dotnet.dll] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets  262

Comment: Did you uninstall the 1.0.0 version when upgrading?

Comment: yes. I manage now to build my apps without error but my problem now is when I try to run my web api it doesnt' start 

I get this error message.

Unable to start debugging. The startup project cannot be launched

Comment: Well then just install 1.0 again :) .net Core has save side-by-side install.

Comment: Did you update the reference of the 1.0 to 1.1 in the global.json?

Comment: Go to C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk and rename all other folders except the version you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have 1.0 and 1.1 installed side-by-side.

The `dotnet` command (*dotnet.dll*) will run according to the SDK version which is written in your "global.json" file (for the Visual Studio Solution) or in the "project.json" file (for the project).

For example on my Windows 10, I have

- .NET Core 1.0 installed in *C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-003131*
- .NET Core 1.1 installed in *C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview2-1-003177*

By default my command is .NET Core 1.1 (the version if I run `dotnet.exe` located in *C:\Program Files\dotnet*) but if I want to run a Visual Studio Solution with 1.0 all I need to do is to write it in the global.json:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```